# Spatial Binomial Probability (Darts Question)

Tags: probability, distributions, binomial-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose a dart board divided into four quadrants and suppose $N$ darts are thrown with some unknown probability distribution. Let $p_1$ be the probability the darts fall in the two upper quadrants, $p_2$ be the probability the darts fall in the two right-hand quadrants, and $p_3$ be the probability of falling in the upper right or lower left quadrants. Suppose also $k_1$ darts fall in the two upper quadrants, $k_2$ darts fall in the two right-hand quadrants, and $k_3$ fall in the upper right or lower left quadrants. Can one express
$$P(k_1,k_2|p_1,p_2,p_3)$$
as a product of binomial distributions? What would the solution to this be?

Comment: This is a *multinomial* distribution.

Comment: Yes, the counts in each quadrant are, but I am asking about k1 and k2.

Comment: Right--nevertheless, the distribution is multinomial and you are asking about an event; thus, the solution is a sum of the multinomial probabilities of its elements.

Comment: I am aware, the algebra quickly gets messy when I try to write out the full sum of multinomial probabilities, so I am hoping there is a more intuitive way to approach this.

Comment: I have not worked through this entirely, but perhaps this suggestion might help. Imagine from left to right (then top to bottom) each square is labeled "a,b,c,d". You can write P(k1 = x, k2 = y | p) as P(a + b = k1, b + d = k2 |p). The r.v.s a,b,c,and d are all binomial. The respective "p" parameters can be found using the information from p1, p2, and p3. I hope this is a good start. If somebody finds a better way, I'd be curious to know.